# Phase difference

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, inductance

Is there a phase difference between the magnetic field and the current producing this field?

I have simulation results for three-phase transformer at different frequencies. The spectrum of the current and magnetic field are showing opposite trends (magnetic field is maximum/minimum where current is minimum/maximum).

Can someone explain where this phase difference comes from? Because flux and current are always in-phase.

Comment: have you double-checked you are plotting current and not voltage? that 90º phase shift would be expected with a high inductance between voltage and magnetic field

Answer (score 0):

One possibility; the programming for your simulation may contain an error.  Another possibility;  the flux in a regular transformer depends on both currents (input and output), but I would not expect to see a 90 degree shift.  In an ideal transformer we do expect the voltage to be 90 degrees out of phase with the flux and, under no load conditions, the current to be in phase. I am not familiar with a three phase device, but it would certainly require a more careful analysis.

Comment: the shift is not 180 degrees, it is just 90 degrees. if we consider a single phase as an inductor, can we expect this phase shift?

Comment: I stand corrected.