# What is the phase relationship between current and magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

I understand the phase relationship of the electric and magnetic fields. but what is the phase relationship between current in an inductor and magnetic field produced due to this current?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503280/2451

Comment: Haven't  you already been told there should be no phase shift between the magnetic flux and the current producing that flux.  What else do you need to know?

Comment: phase relation between B and I or H and I. i am not asking about phase of phi and I.